# ERROR: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object String]

Tags: node.js, express

What I am trying to do is simply to get back 'auth user' from the server when I send a HTTP request from Postman.I am just experimenting. Perhaps, my mistake might be obvious, but I have been struggling with this issue. If you could tell what's wrong, that would be greatly appreciated. My shortened code snippet is the following:

server.js

```
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import authRoutes from './routes/authRoutes.js';

const port = process.env.PORT || 9000;

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

app.use('/api/auth', authRoutes);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('API is running...');
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`listening on localhost: ${port}`));
```

authRoutes.js

```
import express from 'express';
import { verifyUser } from '../controllers/authController.js';

const router = express.Router();
router.route('/').get('/auth', verifyUser);

export default router;
```

authController.js

```
import asyncHandler from 'express-async-handler';


const verifyUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send('auth user');
});

export { verifyUser };
```

Comment: `router.route('/').get('/auth', verifyUser);` This is not correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
router.route('/').get('/auth', verifyUser);
```

should be

```js
router.route('/').get(verifyUser);
```

More info about `.route()` function here: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However, when I hit the root endpoint, the "API is running..." message is returned back as the way my implementation does.

Comment: That's because this is your root endpoint. Your auth route is at `/api/auth` because of this line `app.use('/api/auth', authRoutes);`

Comment: glad I helped, happy coding!